# img alt utf-8 (arabic) showing as "missing description" in Alexa report

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

In Alexa report, it's complaining about "missing image description" and it's showing all of our images in over 6,000 page.

Looking at them one by one to find they're all having an alt value, but it's in Arabic (utf-8).

Example:

```
<img src=".." alt="وصف الصورة">
```

I've googled and i didn't get a proper answer, the only thing i found is from html.com https://html.com/attributes/img-alt/ stating:

> "No special characters. This includes UTF-8 characters such as
>   unencoded curly quotes, as well as HTML Character Entities."

But it doesn't seem right to change the language of all these alt descriptions.

Am i missing something here? help me out please.

Comment: Not sure your issue but I'd say `html.com` is wrong. You can have entities in an `alt`, https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/img.html `The alt text can contain entities e.g. for accented characters or special symbols, but it can't contain markup.` Maybe use https://3v4l.org/64mfE

Comment: I've just noticed something common in all these alt images, all of them had double quotes, and they were shown as &quot (html escaped). What should i do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that there's nothing wrong with the Arabic language (UTF-8) itself in the `img alt` but the `&` in the `&quot`.

Most of the alt descriptions i had (which dynamically gets pasted from the article header) have double quotes `"` in them, so if i leave them they will mess up the `alt=""` and it would be `alt=""""`, and escaping them using html_escape function will result in replacing the double quotes with `&quot` which had the `&` in it.
So to solve it, i wrote a function that removes the `"` from any `alt=""` and now Alexa is not complaining about them anymore.